# Insert Data from Excel into Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I've made some code to insert data from an excel table in to an access database - my code is as follow:

```
    Sub AddData()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

'lets connect to the workbook first, I tested this, it works for me
Cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=sample.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;" _
& "Persist Security Info=False"

' Append data from Sheet1 of workbook to Table1 of mydb.mdb:
Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO tblSales IN 'C:\Users\User\Documents\access.mdb' SELECT * FROM [datasheet]"

Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

My problem is when executing this I get the error "Microsoft Jet Engine could not find the path to object "datasheet" . Datasheet is just the name of the sheet where the data is located in my workbook. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you put a $ sign after the sheet name
like this [datasheet$]
?

Comment: It will, if you afdd the full name of the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
xlFilepath = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName
Sql = "INSERT INTO tblSales " & _

"SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & xlFilepath & "].[datasheet$A1:AK10011] "

cnn.Execute Sql
```

Warning in your Datasheet Table The first 8 rows. Assuming theres a Heading (HDR=YES)
the next 6 rows should contain a dummy data to define your columns equivalent to your access table column definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot execute a query on just any open workbook. It MUST be run against a file, that means you have to provide a full path to you sheet, including the filename. If your workbook is "dirty", you need to save it first.
I would rather

- loop the worksheet lines and add the records one by one
- or use the code you just wrote from Access (if it is suitable)

Comment: Looping is slow, ADO is fast. You do not need an open workbook, but you can run ADO against the current workbook, if as you say, you have saved.

Answer (score 0):

All that is missing, as far as I can see, is the path to your data source and a string on datasheet:

```
Data Source=sample.xls;
```

Should read, for example:

```
Data Source=c:\docs\sample.xls;
```

And:

```
SELECT * FROM [datasheet$]
```

Answer (score -1):

The SELECT statement runs on the database itself, but you want to send values from EXCEL. So you must use

```
cn.Execute "INSERT .... VALUES (" & excelcell_or_variable & ");"
```

eventually in a loop to proces all rows/columns etc.

Hope that helps

good luck

EDIT ...
don't forget quotation marks surrounding CHAR's and interpunctations; I use

```
' ....
' .... "...VALUES (" & T(Q(MyStringCell)) & T(MyNumCell) & Q(MyLastTextCell) & ");"
' ....

' surrounds a string by single quotes
Private Function Q(Arg as String) As String
    Q = "'" & Arg & "'"
Return

' appens a comma to a string
Private Function T(Arg as String) As String
    T = Arg & ","
Return
```

EDIT 2
I asume that in EXCEL the values you want to insert into the DB are all in 1 row ...

Suppose you have a source_range which contains more than 1 row, you must fire the INSERT statement for each row in that range. You use the `.Rows` property to return a single row from a range. And you send multiple columns to the INSERT statement within the same row by using `.Cells(1, 1)`, `.Cells(1,2)` .... and so on

example:

```
Sub Test()
Dim MyRange As Range, MyRow As Range

    Set MyRange = Range([B4], [C8])   ' source range

    For Each MyRow In MyRange.Rows    ' get one row at the time from source range 
        Debug.Print MyRow.Cells(1, 1), MyRow.Cells(1, 2)
        ' replace the above by your INSERT statement
    Next MyRow

End Sub
```

Comment: see my edit ... pay attention to the data type receiving the insert; and of course your insert must fulfill all table constraints (i.e. the not null's, references etc.) and be in the format (dates!!) the DB wants to see it

Comment: Thanks for the help - how would this work if I wanted to select a range? for example A:E?

Comment: ahhh .... so I recon you got the quotations and interpunctations right now ... good so ... for the rest see my EDIT 2 ... hope it helps :-)

Comment: This is simply not true. It is quite possible to update from an Excel sheet to Access using ADO. Please reconsider your answer.