# Update data in an Access table from Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I insert data into an Access table from a row in Excel using the code here ([Insert Data from Excel into Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226004/insert-data-from-excel-into-access-using-vba)).

I have a problem when inserting a record that is already in the table because of the same primary key value.

I want to update the record or delete the record and enter a new one with the same key.

```vb
Dim Connect As ADODB.Connection
Set Connect = New ADODB.Connection

Connect.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ExcelFileName.xlsm;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;" & "Persist Security Info=False"
Connect.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_TCM_MAA_Data IN 'C:\DataBaseFileName.accdb' SELECT * FROM [SheetName$A2:O2]"

Connect.Close
Set Connect = Nothing
```

Comment: First run a `select` query to see if the id already exists, then run either an update or an insert depending on the results

Comment: I'm not sure where to add that code or even how. I'm not very familiar of using SQL in VBA. But I added the code that I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
xlFilepath = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName

Set Var = Sheets1.Range("A1")

Connect.Execute "Delete * FROM [TableName] WHERE [Column Name] = " & Var & ""

SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_TCM_MAA_Data " & _

"SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & xlFilepath & "].[SheetName$A2:O2] where [Column Name] > 1"

Connect.Execute SQL
```

Warning in your Datasheet Table The first 8 rows. Assuming theres a Heading (HDR=YES)
the next 6 rows should contain a dummy data to define your columns equivalent to your access table column definition.