# Bidirectional connection between Access DB and Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, database-connection, ms-office

Is there any way to connect an access table to an Excel file having the possibility to modify it from both of them? if I change a record from Excel, it is modified in Access too, and vice versa.

I tried to import the Access table into Excel, but if I modify a record then press "update all", the record returns to its original state.

I am using Office 365.

Comment: You want Excel to connect to Access table then edit Access data from Excel and pass those edits back to Access table? AFAIK, that requires VBA. Why would you want to edit Access from Excel? I inherited a db with that setup and quickly decided to eliminate Excel component.

Comment: I created the database for my company, and most of the people just prefere using Excel and they are faster with it. In the other side, i need to use Access because i created some queries to auto update the database when needed. Can you share the VBA code that permits to do it? Really appreciate ur comment @June7

Comment: What people prefer and what is best for company are two different things. People can learn. I no longer have code for Excel to edit Access data. Here is a taste of what is required https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226004/insert-data-from-excel-into-access. IMHO, the amount of programming required to make it really user-friendly isn't worth the effort. If people want to use Excel to pull data and do some analysis, fine, but use Access to enter/edit data in Access.

Comment: Where exactly are you pressing "update all"?